# Get this content editable to work on firefox and edge

Tags: html, css

I am trying to work with this code. https://codepen.io/fritx/pen/NZpbqW

```css
.editor {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

[contenteditable][placeholder]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  color: gray;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="editor" placeholder="Textarea placeholder..."></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<div class="editor" contenteditable placeholder="Div placeholder..." oninput="if(this.innerHTML.trim()==='<br>')this.innerHTML=''" ></div>
```

The content automatically scrolls down on chrome, but not on firefox or edge. Can anyone help me make it work right on those?

Comment: it's working on Edge

Comment: It already works in both browsers

Comment: On Firefox and Edge, the content keeps gong to the right past the width of the div container, while it should drop down to the next line to stay in the box like it does in chrome.